# OpenGL - Scaling output canvas

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm pretty new to OpenGL, and I was doing some simple tests by using an integer array to draw pixels to the canvas, for example:

```
uint32_t* pixels = new uint32_t[200 * 200] //A 200*200 canvas is assumed
//Get pixels somehow
while(true)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawPixels(pixels, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, pixels);
    glSwapBuffers() //I'm using GLFW, but that's not important
}
```

So far, so good. However, I wanted to try to stretch those pixels out to cover a wider canvas. If I had a 400*400 canvas, for example, I assume that glDrawPixels will only cover 1/4 of the entire drawing area, leaving the rest blank. How can I scale those pixels to fit the whole drawing area, using a nearest-integer method? (I don't care about other filters, just something that will give me a "pixelly" look.)

Comment: Probably the most OpenGL-ic way to do it is to create a texture and set filtering to GL_NEAREST.